# SharePoint 2019 - Why doesn't the People WebPart import all of the information in AD?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2019

I am currently using SharePoint 2019 and I have synced all of my users from AD into our SharePoint environment.  When I add the Peoples Webpart on a new page for testing purposes and then add one of our users to it, only the email and the mobile phone are displayed when hovering over each profile. I would like to figure out why it doesn't display properties like department or their desk phone number. Is there something I have missed during the syncing process?  All of this information is in AD and when I edit the profile in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a limitation of the webpart. It only displays the name and email address.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same experience with you.

As trevor said, [People web part in SharePoint online](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/get-the-most-out-of-the-modern-web-parts-series-the-people-web-part/) and SharePoint server 2019 has different behavior, which has limitation in server.

Comment: There are no customization options through custom code either, I suppose?

Comment: That's correct. You cannot customize/extend the out of the box webparts.